# Reading comments from .proto files using a Protocol Buffers descriptor object

Tags: c++, c++11, protocol-buffers, descriptor, proto3

I am currently revisiting a project using Google [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers).

In the project I want to make use of the features *Descriptors* and *Reflection* of Protocol Buffers.

The official documentation states that the comments of `.proto` files can be read:

1. With the function [`DebugStringWithOptions()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#DebugStringOptions), called on a message or descriptor.
2. With the function [`GetSourceLocation()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#Descriptor.GetSourceLocation.details), called on a descriptor.

I am unable to retrieve comments, so I think I am doing something completely wrong or that feature isn't fully implemented in Protocol Buffers, yet.

Here are some code snippets:

```
google::protobuf::DebugStringOptions options;
options.include_comments = true;
std::cout << "google::protobuf::Descriptor::DebugStringWithOptions(): "
          << message.descriptor()->DebugStringWithOptions(options) << std::endl
          << std::endl;

const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor* field_descriptor{
    message.descriptor()->field(1)};

// TODO(wolters): Why doesn't this work?
google::protobuf::SourceLocation* source_location{
    new google::protobuf::SourceLocation};
field_descriptor->GetSourceLocation(source_location);

// if (field_descriptor->GetSourceLocation(source_location)) {
std::cout << "start_line: " << source_location->leading_comments
          << std::endl;
std::cout << "end_line: " << source_location->leading_comments << std::endl;
std::cout << "start_column: " << source_location->start_column << std::endl;
std::cout << "end_column: " << source_location->end_column << std::endl;
std::cout << "leading_comments: " << source_location->leading_comments
          << std::endl;
std::cout << "trailing_comments: " << source_location->trailing_comments
          << std::endl;
// }
```

I've tried using the following two syntaxes for comments in the `.proto` file,
but none of them seems to work:

```
MessageHeader header = 1;  // The header of this `Message`.

/**
 * The header of this `Message`.
 */
MessageHeader header = 1;
```

I am using GCC 4.7.1 (with C++11 support enabled) and the latest Protocol Buffers version 3.0.0-alpha-4.1.

Can someone guide me into the correct direction and/or provide me an working example?

**EDIT 2015-09-24:**

After rearding the [Self Describing Messages](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#self-description) section in the official documentation and testing lots of stuff, it seems to me that I have a bit better understanding of protobuf descriptors.

Correct me if one or more of the following statements are incorrect:

1. The `SelfDescribingMessage` proto is **only** useful if the other end does not know the .proto definitions.
2. The only way to access the comments of the proto definition is by creating a .desc file using the `protoc` application.
3. To obtain a comment, the GetSourceLocation member function can only be used if the "top" element is either `FileDescriptorSet`, `FileDescriptorProto` or `FileDesriptor`. If this is correct, Protocol Buffers has a poor API design, since the `google::protobuf::Message` class is a God Class (providing access to the complete file descriptor API, but the values are not provided at all).
4. The call `concrete_message.descriptor()->file()` does not (**and** can not) contain source comments information, since it is not part of the compiled code.

It seems to me that the only way to make this work is:

1. Invoke protoc for theMessage.proto file (which references all other messages) with the arguments:

   ```
   --include_imports --include_source_info and --descriptor_set_out=message.desc
   ```
2. Ship the `message.desc` file together with the application/library to be able to read it during runtime (see below).
3. Create a `google::protobuf::FileDescriptorSet` from that file.
4. Iterate over all `google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto` of the `FileDescriptorSet`.
5. Convert each FileDescriptorProto to a `google::protobuf::FileDescriptor` using `google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::BuildFile()`.
6. Lookup the message and/or fields with one of the `Find…` functions, applied on the `FileDescriptor` instance.
7. Call the function `GetSourceLocation` on the message/field descriptor instance.
8. Read the comments via `google::protobuf::SourceLocation::leading_comments` and `google::protobuf::SourceLocation::trailing_comments`.

This seems pretty complicated to me, so I have two additional questions:

1. Isn't there a way to include the source information without using a FileDescriptorSet?
2. Is it possible to "connect"/set the `FileDescriptorSet` with a concrete Message class/instance, since that would drastically simplify things?

**EDIT 2015-09-25:** By *God Class* I mean that the `Message` class and/or the descriptor classes offer public functions that are more or less useless, since they provide no information when used by a client. Take a "normal" message for example: So the generated code does **not** contain source comment information, therefore the `GetSourceLocation` method in all descriptor classes (e.g. `Descriptor` and `FieldDescriptor`) is completely useless. From a logical perspective separate instances `DescriptorLite` and `FieldDescriptorLite` should be provided if dealing with messages and `Descriptor` and `FieldDescriptor` if dealing with information from a `FileDescriptorSet` (whose source is normally a .desc file generated from a .proto file). A `[...]Lite` class would then be the parent class of a "normal" class. The argument that `protoc` will possibly never include source comments, underlines my point.

By "connecting", I mean an API function to **update** the descriptor information in the message with the descriptor information from the .desc file (which is always a superset of the descriptors provided by the message, if I understood correctly).

Comment: Is it possible that it is related to the Protocol Buffers Compiler `protoc`? I've just stumbled upon the `protoc` arguments `-o` and `--include_source_info`. Do I have to create a `FileDescriptorSet` in order to retrieve comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you've basically figured it out.

You're getting deep into APIs inside the protocol compiler which were not really designed for public consumption. It gets complicated because no one has written a helper layer to simplify things, because not many people use these features.

I am not sure what you mean about `Message` being a "God class". `Message` is merely the abstract interface for a protobuf instance. Descriptors describe *types* of protobuf instances. `Message::getDescriptor()` returns the type of a message, but beyond that there isn't much direct connection between these APIs...

> Isn't there a way to include the source information without using a FileDescriptorSet?

The comments are intentionally stripped from the descriptors embedded into the generated code, so you need to run the parser separately, generate a descriptor set, and consume it dynamically.

> Is it possible to "connect"/set the FileDescriptorSet with a concrete Message class/instance, since that would drastically simplify things?

Do you mean that you want Message::getDescriptor() to return a descriptor that includes the comment data from the source file? That would require that the comment data be embedded into generated code, which would be trivial for `protoc` to implement (it currently intentionally strips them out, so it would just have to *not* do that) but potentially bloat-y and dangerous (could reveal secrets for people shipping closed-source binaries built with protobufs).

Comment: Thank you for your comment and the explaination! I've updated my question again for clarification. I will add a working example later, maybe someone can review it then.

Comment: @FlorianWolters Thanks for the clarification. I disagree with the suggestion, though: source locations are an obscure, rarely-used part of the descriptor interface. It doesn't make sense to add complexity to the class hierarchy specifically to distinguish descriptors with and without source info. Plus, some Message subclasses (like DynamicMessage) could actually have source info in their descriptors. (Of course, I don't work on protobufs anymore so it's not my call in any case.)